# Formio.js get JSON text from builder method

Tags: javascript, formio

I read the docs about formio.js on github. But I can't see how to get json text after the form is build.

Here's my code:

```
<div id='builder'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var builder = Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}, {});

    builder.then(function(form){
        form.on("change", function(e){
             console.log("Something changed on the form builder");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I want to take the json schema of the form to store in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
...
form.on("change", function(e){
    console.log("Something changed on the form builder");
    var jsonSchema = JSON.stringify(form.submission, null, 4);
    console.log(jsonSchema); // this is the json schema of form components
});
...
```

or you could try using `builder.instance.schema`, as
...

```
form.on("change", function(e){
    console.log("Something changed on the form builder");
    var jsonSchema = JSON.stringify(builder.instance.schema, null, 4);
    console.log(jsonSchema);
});
...
```

Comment: It returns `undefined`

Comment: It said the `builder.instance` in undefined.

Comment: @MrHery Pls check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kaftLenq/3/ , seems to work for me with form.submission

Comment: Your answer is correct. But I dont know why my code not working. I viewing the source page of view-source:https://formio.github.io/formio.js/app/builder and it seem they are use `new Formio.FormBuilder` so that's why can access the `builder.instance`. But I am using `Formio.builder`, it should be accessible to `form.submission`, but just not working for me. Maybe got other script block. So now I am using the `new Formio.FormBuilder` instead of `Formio.builder`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this answered already, but for those who want to still use `Formio.builder` instead of `new Formio.FormBuilder` you can try this:

```
Formio.builder(document.getElementById('builder'), {}).then(function(form){
  form.on("change", function(e){
    console.log(form.schema);
  });
});
```

Comment: created a jsfiddle to support the claim https://jsfiddle.net/mdrLgcuh/